# complex regex aspnet

Tags: regex

I want to use regular expression validation control in my asp.net site that allow alphanumeric characters and urdu language characters. Any idea how I use unicode in regular expression? Special characters are not allowed.

Any working example will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Read this: [Encoding Urdu in Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urdu#Encoding_Urdu_in_Unicode). As you can see, since many Urdu characters are confusable with Arabic ones, you'll have to give more details about your requirements. anyway you'll have to construct a character class, like `[\u06C1\u06BE`...`]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex regex = new Regex( "[\u0600-\u06ff]|[\u0750-\u077f]|[\ufb50-\ufc3f]|[\ufe70-\ufefc]"); return regex.IsMatch(text);